# How to code Spring JPA onetomany relation

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring programming and trying the below example with one to many relationship between BID and BIDITEM classes. I am not sure whether the BIDITEM data is saved, as when I tried to retrieve the BID, I am getting only BID data and not BIDITEM data. Do we need to have a repository even for BIDITEM class. I can see that complete BID JSON string, along with BIDITEM is received in create method.
    Could you please go through it, and let me know what is wrong with it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bid")
public class Bid {
    @Id
    private String title;
    @Column
    private long startDate;
    @Column
    private long endDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myBid", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<BidItem> bidItems = new ArrayList<BidItem>();
//Constructor, getter and setter methods go here    
}   

@Entity
@Table(name="biditem")
public class BidItem 
{
    @Id
    private String item;
    @Column
    private String desc;
    @Column
    private double minAmt;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "title")
    private Bid myBid;  
//Constructor, getter and setter methods go here
}   

public interface BidRepository extends CrudRepository<Bid, String> {
//Tried even JpaRepository

}

public class BidService {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    @Autowired
    private BidRepository bidRepo;

    public Bid create(String bidJson) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        Bid bid = mapper.readValue(bidJson, Bid.class);     

//   bidJson string has below string 
//   {"bidItems":[{"item":"item1","desc":"item1","minAmt":"999"}],
//    "title":"bid1","startDate":"D1","endDate":"D5"}

        Bid savedBid = bidRepo.save(bid);
        return savedBid;
    }
    public Bid findByID(String title)
    {
        Bid bid = bidRepo.findOne(title);
        return bid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you've specified `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on the field `bidItems` in class `Bid`, the bit items will be saved as well when you save the bid. You did however not show us how you are dealing with transactions and when exactly you are calling the `create` and `findByID` methods. Do you see the items in the database if you look in the DB with a DB management tool?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not using any transactions and am using H2 in-memory database. Create and findByID are called from RestController methods, whenever there is web request to create new bid or find for any existing bid.

Comment: I could see both the tables got populated in H2 database. But the BidItem.title is null.

Comment: Did you set the field `myBid` in your `BidItem` object before saving the `Bid` entity? You'll need to do that yourself, JPA is not automatically setting both sides of the association for you.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot Jesper.